# Tracking what commands were executed after sudo to another user

Tags: linux, redhat

I have provided sudo to ten users to become another user like oracle

I want to track which user executes which command after they become oracle. If there is a way to store the log files in a common file that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

[this article](https://nixhive.com/log-sudo-commands/) describe a way to setup a log file. In a `Defaults` section while using `visudo` command : `logfile=/var/log/sudo`